# Can I mix bash script in HTcondor script?

Tags: condor

i am submitting a job to condor. The arguments that are passed to the executable are numerical values generated by bash script. Is it possible to mix up the condor and bash script in such a way ?

```
for fp in $(seq 1.0 .01 1.1)
do
     Arguments= $fp
     Queue

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
universe = vanilla
executable = my_program
arguments = $(arg)


queue arg from seq 1.0 .01 1.1 |
```

The pipe (|) character at the end of the queue statement says "assign to the local variable "arg" the successive values of running the "seq" program.

Comment: Thanks. I tested, it worked as I wanted.